# How to prove the MLE for theta?

Tags: normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood

[image]

I started off with finding L(Xij; θ), but I'm still struggling to get to this equation in the problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please mark this with the "Self-Study" tag. One approach would be to use a Lagrangian, are you familiar with those?